# Bootstrap typeahead does not work with ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using the Yii Booster extension that wraps the Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 library into a usable Yii extension. I have a typeahead field, which fetches data using AJAX calls (using jQuery's `ajax()` function). The code that creates the typeahead field is:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTypeahead', array(
  'model'=>$expense,
  'attribute'=>'afm',
  'htmlOptions'=>array('autocomplete'=>'off'),
  'options'=>array(
    'source'=>'js:function(query, process) {
      $.ajax({url: "' . $urlAfm . '", data: {query: query}, dataType: "json" })
      .done(function(data) {
        return process(data);
      })}',
    'updater'=>'js:function(item) {
      return item;
    }',
    'highlighter'=>'js:function(item) {
      return item;
    }',
  )));
```

The corresponding controller action that returns the JSON data is:

```
public function actionAjxGetAFM($query = '') {
  if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && trim($query) != '') {
    $companies = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT name FROM company WHERE afm '
      . 'LIKE :match LIMIT 10')->queryColumn(array(':match'=>$query . '%'));
    Yii::trace(print_r(CJSON::encode($companies), true));
    echo CJSON::encode($companies);
    Yii::app()->end();
  }
  echo '0';
}
```

No matter what I tried, no list appears after entering the first character. What am I doing wrong?

The JSON response from the controller action is something like:

```
["\u039b\u03bf\u03cd\u03c1\u03b4\u03b1\u03c2 \u0392\u03b1\u03c3\u03af\u03bb\u03b5\u03b9\u03bf\u03c2","\u039c\u03bf\u03c5\u03c1\u03b1\u03c4\u03af\u03b4\u03bf\u03c5 \u039c\u03b1\u03c1\u03af\u03b1","\u03a0\u03bf\u03bb\u03c5\u03c7\u03c1\u03cc\u03bd\u03b7\u03c2 \u039b\u03bf\u03cd\u03c1\u03b4\u03b1\u03c2"]
```

Comment: So you diagnose this like this: 1. What errors do you see from the browser's JavaScript console and dev tools? 2. Does the JavaScript that actually gets delivered to the browser look right? 3. Does the ajax call get made? 4. Does the data that comes back from it look right?

Comment: 1. No errors in the browser's console. 2. Yes, I can see the output from Firebug's console window, it seems right. 3. Yes, the action is fired, if I add a `Yii::trace()` call, I see it in the application's log file. 4. Yes, it looks right.

Comment: @ Vasileios: You need to check 3 and 4 *on the browser*, not the server.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the ajax call is made, I can see it in Firebug, plus the response, a JSON encoded value, regardless of the server log file.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('autocomplete'=>'off'),
```

change it to

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('autocomplete'=>'on'),
```